# Mongodb get element value from another collection based on its _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mean-stack

I'm trying to get an element value based on a result _id in an aggregation.

This is the aggregation:

```
$project: {
  _id: 0,
  brand: "$_id",
  "options": {
    $mergeObjects: "$ram"
  },
  sum: {
    $add: [
      "$sm",
      1
    ]
  }
}
```

And I want brand to get the name from other collection named "brands" which looks like this

```
    [
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("617b0dbacda6cbd1a0403f68"),
    "SerialNumber": "45454234324",
    "name": "hp"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("617b0dbacda6cbd1a0403f69"),
    "SerialNumber": "azazz5245454az",
    "name": "asus"
  }]
```

What I want to get is the name of brand using using its _id based on the result _id.
Using SQL its something like this:

```
Get brands.name where _id=brands._id
```

Comment: You can "join" two collections (using a common field to match) using the `$lookup` aggregation stage.

Answer (score 0):

i managed to do it using $lookup

```
{
                $lookup:
                {
                    from: "brands",
                    localField: "brand",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "brand"
                }
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    brand: "$brand.brand"     
                }
            },
```